# Match the values of 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, matching, cosine-similarity

I am trying to create a program that will rate a bunch of arrays to find the one that most closely matches a given array. So say the given array is

```
[1, 80, 120, 155, 281, 301]
```

And one of the array to compare against is

```
[-6, 78, 108, 121, 157, 182, 218, 256, 310, 408, 410]
```

How can I match up the values in the first array to their closes values in the second array that will give it the lowest total difference.
In case this is unclear

`1 => -6, 80 => 78, 120 => 121, 155 => 157`

Than 281 should match up to 310 since it is closer than 256 however this would force 301 to match to 256. So the best overall match would be

`281=>256 and 301=> 310`

Then the program would simply calculate a rating by doing

`abs(-6 - 1) + abs(78-80)` etc for all matches. And the array with the lowest rating is the best match

*******NOTE*******

The given array will be the same size or smaller than the matching array and will only have positive values. The matching array can have negative values.
I was thinking of using cosine similarity but I am unsure how to implement that for this problem.

Comment: You can compute the distance between arrays to determine the similarity. Is there noise in the data? Is the data linear?

Comment: There are no values that should be ignored (noise), and the arrays will be sorted to be linear. How do you calculate the distance?

Answer (score 0):

In general a computed distance is more accurate. There are [different approaches](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) with advantages and disadvantages. In your example you compute the sum of [one dimension euclidean distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#One_dimension). But there are more extended comparisons like the [dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). It's an algorithm, which finds the best alignment between two 'arrays' and computes the optimal distance.

You can install and use [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dtw/1.2) package. [Here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pierre-rouanet/dtw/blob/master/simple%20example.ipynb) you can see a visual example. One other advantage of the DTW is, that the length of the arrays don't have to be matched.

Comment: I am trying to write this code in ruby is there a ruby gem that gives DTW calculations

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize the programming language. (In detail you use the word `array` instead of `list`.) Anyway I found this rubygem: https://rubygems.org/gems/dtw